# Reading NFC tags only from a particuar activity

Tags: android, nfc

Ill first tell you what I am doing. I have three activities in the sequence,

Activity1>>Activity2>>Activity3. Now I want to read NFC tags only from the Activity2 when I tap on the tag. My app should not be able to read the tags when I am in the Activity1 or Activity3. How am I supposed to this, Is there any enabling/disabling option? any property to set for the same? I dont want to prompt the user to enable/disable NFC from the Settings for this purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a foreground application, your app will always have the chance to react first on the touched tag. So what you need to do is to enable forgraoundDsipatch for your activities, and on Activity1 and Activity3 just to ignore the event, and on Activity2 process the information of the touched tag. Otherwise if your app do not take the event of the detected tag, the android dispatch system will continue to search suitable application to trigger and when it find it it will start it on top of your app.

For more information on Foreground Dispatch look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch

Comment: so should i set null parameters for enableForegroundDispatch() for activity1 and activity3? If so, I did it in the onCreate(), but there is a force close due to null pointer exception. Ive used enableForegroundDispatch() for activity2.

Comment: You can use null for filters and techLists, but for the pendingIntent you should specify which class will take care of tag parsing.

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

Answer (score 0):

Only set an intent-filter for whichever NFC intent you are interested in on Activity2.  See the Android [NFC Demo AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/AndroidManifest.html) for an example.

Comment: Yes, It was the first thing I did in my app.. My question is, how can I prevent my app from reading tags whether it be in Activity1 or Activity3. It should read tags only in Activity2.