# Android NFC Tags

Tags: android, tags, nfc

We have an application that is using NFC tags to allow people to log in.

The log in screen appears, the user swipes the tag and in they go - all is good.

Now for the problem :

As it is impossible to turn off the reader from code, can anyone suggest how I get the device to ignore any further attempts to read and NFC tag until the user has logged out again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android app enable NFC only for one Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059027/android-app-enable-nfc-only-for-one-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add different listener for the NFC while the user is logged in?

So if the tag is used while the user is logged in, instead of trying to log in again it just presents a toast that states "You are already logged in"

Or better yet have the app check if the user is already logged in before triggering the logging in event.

Comment: Would "a different listener" make more sense than "another listener"? The latter implies two listeners, including the original, now problematic one.

Comment: You're right. No sense in adding more code to fix an existing problem when you can just fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes it just takes someone to give a nudge in the right direction.  This Android lark is all new to me.  Your help is appreciated