# Make sure NFC is turned off in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

In my React Native app, one of the screens shows the QR code. That QR code should be placed to the QR code reader, which has also NFC capabilities.

My task is to make sure that the NFC is turned off. Yep, my app does not have any NFC features or capabilities. No permissions are set in AndroidManifest or Info.plist.

That is just a QR code provider (NS from the Netherlands) requirement to make sure the NFC is off. How to make it?

Is that possible that another app somehow uses NFC at this time?

Update:

Generally, the issue is with Apple Pay and Google Pay. While trying to scan the QR code from the screen both payment applications are popped up, which prevents reading the QR code.

So the idea is just to disable those payment applications while using our app.

- for iOS is possible to use entitlement https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation
- did not find something similar for Android yet.

> related issue on Github https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager/issues/455

Comment: For iOS you can apply to Apple for a special [entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH7-SW3) that allows your app to turn off NFC detection so that Apple Pay is not triggered in this scenario.

Comment: Really need to have more detail on the QR code Reader, is it's NFC capabilities as a NFC Reader or as an NFC Tag?

Comment: The general solution is to disable Apple Pay and Google Pay.
* Apple instruction http://www.codereviewcache.com/disable-apple-pay/

Answer (score 1):

I had to use NFC capabilities in a RN app. This is the package I've used: https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager. The setup is simple on Android but can be tricky on iOS: https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager/blob/main/setup.md

You have methods such as `isEnabled(): Promise<boolean>;` or `isSupported(): Promise<boolean>;`. I believe they will be enough for you.

Disclaimer:
I never tried to use those functions to check that directly: I usually check for the changes in the state since I need to give out some warnings.

Also I don't simply check for on or off. I use something because I need to make sure the iPhone can use the NFC for read/write (and not just payments)

```js
try {
    await NfcManager.isSupported(NfcTech.Iso15693IOS);
} catch (error) {
    // set state = off and unsupported
```

Comment: On Android at least you cannot programmatically turn NFC off, you have to prompt the user to do that, I guess you might have the same problem with iOS but are not sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with Apple Pay and Google Pay is as follow:

- try to scan the QR code on a mobile device
- Actual behavior: payment application is popped up
- Expected behavior: QR stays on the screen

So the idea is just to disable those payment applications while using our app.

- Guide how to disable Apple Pay http://www.codereviewcache.com/disable-apple-pay/
- Hint how to disable Google Pay [Android app enable NFC only for one Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059027/android-app-enable-nfc-only-for-one-activity)

Comment: did you managed to find any solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. I plan to publish the full available info next week. Do not hesitate to poke me, if I forget.

Comment: please do, i have similar issue with my project that i need to fix it would be big help

Comment: Hey, Any Update on this i really need this

Comment: Can you please provide solution to this?

Comment: @AlexAymkin any chance to post your solution here? I'm running into the exact same issue (thanks to the Netherlands) and while I think I have a solution for Apple, I'm not quite sure about Google just yet :D