# Android Studio disable NFC

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, nfc

How can I make NFC tag scanning happen only in selected activities? Currently, scanning takes place in every activity and every time the phone is applied to the tag.
I tried to solve the problem from this link but the application does not turn on at all.
[Android app enable NFC only for one Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059027/android-app-enable-nfc-only-for-one-activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.nfc_scanner">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFC_Scanner"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- MAIN represents that it is the Main Activity-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!-- Launcher Denotes that it will be the first launching activity-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RentActivity"
            tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AddingCostumesActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/tech_list" />
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"
        tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" />


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So only the user can actually disable NFC by going to the settings BUT you emulate that by handling NFC in **every** Activity and just doing nothing when a `Tag` is detected in Activities that you want it to look like NFC is disabled.

To do this I would use the better `enableReaderMode` API [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921434/2373819) as you can also turn off the NFC sound with that API (plus it is more reliable especially for writing and also automatically handles NFC in a non UI thread as per documentation and does not have `pause` and `resume` your app to send it NFC data).

This is very similar to the answer you linked to but also silences the detection sound.

So remove the manifest filter lines

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
     android:resource="@xml/tech_list" />
```

Implement `enableReaderMode` in all Activity classes and if you want to make it look like NFC is disabled then use an `onTagDiscovered` method of:-

```
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why remove intent-filter?

Comment: Suggested Intent-filter removal as a simplification as using the foreground method has no need for the filter and you can get in to problems with some launch modes and navigation structures. It is possible to keep it if you want to be able to launch you application (possibly via a chooser screen) via NFC

Comment: could you tell what to put in the function onTagDiscovered? If I want my activity not to detect NFC tag.

Comment: As in the answer make it an empty method (as the system cannot not detect nfc Tags, you are just emulating not detecting them by detecting them silently and then doing nothing)