# Trying to ignore all NFC intents while in foreground with enableForegroundDispatch

Tags: android, nfc, android-applicationrecord

I'm trying to get my app to ignore nfc commands while running - its launched by an NFC tag with an Android Application Record (AAR), and I dont want it to be able to be launched by that when its already running.. I've tried to carefully follow others [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748513/reading-nfc-tags-only-from-a-particuar-activity), but the app is still able to be launched by AARs while running (in foreground).

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<application>
    <activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/com.MyApp.frontcam" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Activity.java:**

```
private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
private String[][] mTechLists;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndef.addDataType("*/*");  
    }
    catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
    mTechLists = new String[][] {
            new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() },
            new String[] { Ndef.class.getName() },
            new String[] { NdefFormatable.class.getName() }
    }; 

}

@Override 
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null); //ended up setting mFilters and mTechLists to null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting launchmode:

```
<application>
    <activity android:launchmode="singleTask">
    ...
```

> **singleTask**: The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Tried adding that to the Manifest.xml but kept my activity.java file and its still not working.. Is there a problem with my activity.java coding?

Comment: This worked well for a react-native app that was using NFC internally.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `foregroundDispatch` a new intent will be given to your activity when you scan a tag. You should overwrite the `onNewIntent` method. Add something like this:

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.nfctest;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    doSomethingWithIntent(this.getIntent());        
}   

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Enable forground dispatching to get the tags
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null); //ended up setting mFilters and mTechLists to null
}   

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //You need to disable forgroundDispatching here
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}   

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent data) {
    //Catch the intent your foreground dispatch has launched
    doSomethingWithIntent(data);    
}

private void doSomethingWithIntent(Intent data) 
{ 
    //Get the tag from the given intent
    Tag tag = data.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if(tag != null)
    {
        //Tag is found
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enjoy your tag.", 3).show();      
    }
    else
    {
        //This was an intent without a tag
        Toast.makeText(this, "This was an intent without a tag.", 3).show();    
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfctest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

You don't need to define the `SINGLE_TOP` mode in your manifest because you already did this in your `mPendingIntent`. And i beleave, even when you leave the flagg here to, it still will call the `onNewIntent` instead of the `onCreate`.

Comment: still nada.. I thought I dont need to specify filters or techlists because I want to ignore all nfc intents?

Comment: I'm sorry, it must have been early. Let me provide you a new answer!

Comment: Interesting snippit of code! Curiously, the app tells me that "This was an intent without a tag.", even when I relaunch the program with a tag. I've tried assigning tag with ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED and  ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED with no luck either..

Comment: It's independent of which intent filter you use in the manifest because the tag will be catch by the foregroundDispatch system, which is defined as a wildcard (catch all tags). I updated my answer with some code. This should work if you put this in your MainActivity. Hope it will help you further!

Comment: great! detects the tag now, but still relaunches the app (only with  "Enjoy your tag.") written. How can I get it to ignore the intent all together?

Comment: That's odd.. What's happening if you delete the intent filter in your manifest? Does it show "Enjoy your tag" without relaunching the application?

Comment: Removed the intent filter on the manifest - still says "enjoy your tag" when the app is re-launched.

Comment: That's odd, the exact same code works for me.. It shouldn't matter but can you try to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your `MainActivity`?