# NFC needs to scan the tag twice

Tags: android, nfc

The question is same as [Reading Data from NFC Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453658/reading-data-from-nfc-tag/25851852#25851852)

When I am trying to read data i need to scan the tag twice. Once to launch the application and another time for application to read data. What should I do so that the application can read data as soon as I scan the tag for the first time. Waiting for your reply.

Anyone has answers for above question? I also face this problem and i have no idea to solve it. Please help it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Data from NFC Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453658/reading-data-from-nfc-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your intent filter catch it, the method `onCreate` will be invoked. Try to add the line below in your `onCreate` method.

`readFromTag( getIntent() );`.

Check this answer for more information about catching a tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25831704/1852589

Comment: Thanks. But my case is NFC scan the tag which is a hardware device, the first scan is send the command to hardware device, and couldn't read back the data synchronized.

For example, mobile phone scan the tag and send the data 123, then mobile phone should read back 456. Unfortunately, it couldn't read 456. But only mobile phone scan the tage again, then mobile can read back 456.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't read well. I thought you also asked the question you linked to. I understand your question and the problem, but can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: I am sorry that i am not a programer, but i am just a project manage man. So, i haven't the code. But i can show you what analyser says by following. Hopefully, it's helpful to see the issue.

Comment: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1k, 9% free 12817K/14004K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
In onNewIntent method
NFC TAG has been received…!
Performing TAG reading and writing has been performed..!
UnAble to Write Mifare Tag 05000… (A number string)
Command sent to hardware is 05000… (A number string)
By Ab: first wait of 8 second is over
Size of byte read from hardware: - 16
Readed NDef Message is: Hello, World! (It should be a number of string)
Tag data is :Hello, world!
Tag data is :Hello, world!
By Ab:-Data readed from tag successfully
By Ab: second wait of 1 second is over
Size of byte read from hardware:-16

Comment: Readed NDef Message is: Hello, World! (It should be a number of string)
Tag data is :Hello, world!
Tag data is :Hello, world!
By Ab:- Data readed from tag successfully
Finally Write Into Tag 05000… (A number string)
In onResume method
Enableing the Data transfer
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1692K, 21% free 11195K/14004K, paused 25ms, total 25ms

Comment: Sorry i can't give you an solution without any code, but i think the problem is related to my answer. Probably your analyzers are not catching the tag's intent when it's invoked via the manifest file. The first time when the app is launched it will invoke the `onCreate` method where you probably don't catch the tag's event. The second time it might be invoke the `onNewIntent` where you do catch the tag.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it will help you further. Good luck!